# R Project File Path Credentials?

Tags: r, file, path, permissions, credentials

I'm working in the following version of R at the bottom. Thanks to the help earlier I was able to use file path code to get data from my H drive, but to go out on my company's network, where  special permissions are required for access to the various folders, I get an error basically saying the path cannot be opened or the file does not exist.:

> Data1 <- read.table(file="/Head-Location-001/MarketingAnalysis/Competitive Intelligence/Stick Rate/Last week/Test.csv", sep = ",", header=TRUE)
>   Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file '/fknp-sfs-001/fknmktanlys/Competitive Intelligence/Stick Rate/Last week/Test.csv': No such file or directory

Is there a way to add credentials to the code that allows it to navigate fo.ders with permissions, and retrieve data? The large data I obtained R to program against cannot be placed on my H drive or home computer:

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

Comment: Ask your IT Admin what are the relative and absolute paths to the folder you want to open and try both.

Comment: Looking at your additional data, it is clear that your network has relative and absolute paths. I don't know which is which but they are: `/fknp-sfs-001/fknmktanlys/` and `/Head-Location-001/`. I would also advise to add the drive identifier beforehand. (`H:/Head-Location-001/..`

Comment: Relative and absolute, ok, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: The address bar doesn't display a letter divider before the slash. First place where I've ever seen that. But I'll ask if there is some designation, though it's not displaying.